# Rails AR query between hour and minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Rails 3 app, pg adapter, my schema look as:

```
create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
 t.integer  "event_type_id"
 t.datetime "start_at"
 #...
end
```

Some example data include:

```
p.events.each{|e| puts e.start_at }; 1
2009-03-23 08:30:00 UTC
2009-05-20 07:45:00 UTC
2009-05-20 07:45:00 UTC
2009-03-23 16:00:00 UTC
2009-05-20 10:00:00 UTC
2009-03-23 19:30:00 UTC
2009-03-23 11:30:00 UTC
2009-05-20 07:45:00 UTC
2009-05-20 07:45:00 UTC
2009-05-20 09:00:00 UTC
2009-05-20 07:45:00 UTC
```

I'd like to search in between the next 3 hours, but ignoring the day! **Hour and minute** is all that matters to me..
Is it possible to be done in Postgres? I've been trying to use [pg EXTRACT()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT), but no  success so far

I don't want to filter all dates in ruby code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the minutes, and only taking into account the hours:

```
#On my model    
scope :next_3_hours, ->(h){
  where( [" date_part( 'hour', \"start_at\") = ? OR date_part( 'hour', \"start_at\") = ? OR date_part( 'hour', \"start_at\") = ? ",h,h+1,h+2])
    .order("date_part( 'hour', \"start_at\") ASC, date_part( 'minute', \"start_at\")")
}
```

result:

```
# on SQL (considering now to be 17:00)
SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
WHERE ( date_part( 'hour', "start_at") = 17 
        OR date_part( 'hour', "start_at") = 18
        OR date_part( 'hour', "start_at") = 19 )
ORDER BY date_part( 'hour', "start_at") ASC, date_part( 'minute', "start_at")
```

Answer (score 1):

I introduce only one way how this can be done in PostgreSQL. I've no RoR experience so I can't help you on that part.

The basic idea below is that all timestamps are converted to the same day so the hours and minutes can be compared:

1. convert timestamps to strings that include only hours an minutes
2. converting that string back to a timestamp causes the date part to be 1st Jan at year 1

---

```
create table test (id serial, start_at timestamp);

insert into test(start_at)
select * from generate_series('2008-03-01 00:00'::timestamp,
                              '2008-03-15 12:00', '5 hours');

with 
hh24mi_now as (select to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI'))
select * from test where id in (
  select id
    from test
   where to_timestamp(to_char(start_at, 'HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI') >= (select * from hh24mi_now)
     and to_timestamp(to_char(start_at, 'HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI') < (select * from hh24mi_now) + interval '3 hours'
  )
order by id
;
```

Result of an example run:

```
 id |      start_at       
----+---------------------
 13 | 2008-03-03 12:00:00
 18 | 2008-03-04 13:00:00
 23 | 2008-03-05 14:00:00
 37 | 2008-03-08 12:00:00
 42 | 2008-03-09 13:00:00
 47 | 2008-03-10 14:00:00
 61 | 2008-03-13 12:00:00
 66 | 2008-03-14 13:00:00
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! That is a too advanced pg code for me =) If you can, please take a look at my solution?